# Best practice for pylons app global tmpl_context settings?

Tags: python, pylons

I'm writing a pylons application, and I'm wondering if there is a best practice for where to set some application specific values of the template context object (`tmpl_context`)?

Currently, I've added a `__before__()` method to the BaseController and am setting up the `tmpl_context` object with values there but am wondering if there is another place.

Answer (score 0):

I think the BaseController is a good place to put that, either in `__call__()` or in `__before__()`.

Answer (score 0):

a `__before__` method is a right place to do it.